# Django ManyToMany relation - check for existence?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I am currently learning Django and building a twitter-like app for that purpose.

I have used a ManyToManyField in my Profile model to reflect followers as such:

### models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """
        Extension of User model to save additional information
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='Followers', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    follower_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now I am trying to check if a user is already following another user (when opening the profile so that I can display the correct follow/unfollow button there)

### views.py

```
def profile(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("User does not exist")
    is_following = True if user.id in Profile.followers.all() else False

    return render(request, 'songapp/profile.html', {'user_profile': user_profile,
                                                    'user'        : user,
                                                    'is_following': is_following})
```

The issue lies within

```
Profile.followers.all()
```

As I get the following AttributeError:

```
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
```

I already used the search function and read through results up to 8 years old but I either did not find or understand the corresponding answer.

Any help is highly appreciated

EDIT: A picture of the Model
[image: Modelpicture]

Comment: You are trying to get M2M records through the model instead of model instance. This should be something more specific. Try this, for example `Profile.objects.filter(id=1).followers.all()`

Comment: With that I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'followers'`- but that's a change, so we might be on the right track.

Comment: oh, sorry, forgot the detail about "more specific" I mentioned: `Profile.objects.filter(id=1).last().followers.all()`

Comment: Sorry, no luck again. `AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'followers'` this is why I came here - no matter the suggestion, something seems wrong

Comment: With `Profile.objects.all()`I get a QuerySet of my 2 set up profiles. One is following the other but that's information I cannot get anywhere

Comment: Any chance that you forgot to run migration? It's strange that it's not working while you do have set `symmetrical=False` on M2M field. Just wonder what will be the output if you call this `Profile._meta.get_fields()`

Comment: Pretty sure that migrations have been done. Result of meta.get_fields: `songapp.models.Profile._meta.get_fields()
(<ManyToOneRel: songapp.follow>, <ManyToOneRel: songapp.follow>, <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField: user>, <django.db.models.fields.TextField: bio>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: follower_count>, <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: following_count>)`

Comment: You are my hero today! I really forgot to makemigrations and migrate ONCE and therefore the manytomany relationship was not working correctly. Cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Hah, glad it helped! You can up-vote my comment if that was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996863/charnel

I got to try migrations again and I really missed one of them. 
Ran `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to get my model working.